# A faster way to create index?

Tags: mysql

I ran an "alter table create index" on a mysql table with over 100 million rows the other day. It ended up taking a while. My coworker advised me to try a shortcut. It doesn't make any sense to me though. The shortcut:

1. use mysqldump to export all the data from the table to a file
2. truncate the table
3. optimize table
4. alter the table
5. import the data back in to the table from the file

Is this actually faster, and if so why?

Comment: no, it's not faster at all

Comment: nopes, it's the same thing. It may be even slower. Since you have 100+ M rows, there's no short cuts.

Comment: I suspected this might be the case since the import has been running since yesterday morning.